# Prove sequences {$a_n$} {$b_n$} of complex numbers converge

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, summation

Prove that if {$a_n$} and {$b_n$} are sequences of complex numbers such that $a_n$ = $b_{n+1}$ - $b_n$ for any $n$ $\in$ $\Bbb Z$$^+$ , then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges iff $\lim_ {n\to \infty} b_n$ exists, in which case we have

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ = $\lim_{n\to \infty} b_n - b_1$

I'm so lost on this. How do I approach it? Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the partial sums $S_N=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}a_n$. By definition, $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{N}a_n$ converges if and only if $S_N$ converges (*i.e.*, $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty} S_N$ exists and is finite).

Can you see these are telescoping, and so can you write down explicitly what $S_N$ is?

Comment: but once I have the partial sum, how does that help me?

Comment: Okay. The partial sum is $$S_N=a_1+a_2+\cdots + a_N$$ $$=(b_2-b_1)+(b_3-b_2)+\cdots + (b_{N+1}-b_N)$$ $$=b_{N+1}-b_1$$ So the infinite series converges iff $S_N$ converges (by definition), and $S_N$ converges iff $b_{N+1}-b_1$ converges (they're the same thing), and that converges iff $b_N$ converges.

Comment: oh my goodness I feel so silly. Thank you so much. This was much simpler than I had anticipated.